# How to find these semi-transparent blue pixels via OpenCV?

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing

I have a range of images that look similar to this:

[image: Sample image]

The images sometimes have these blue-ish areas, but as you can see, their color values are in a broad range. I need to find that blue blob, so I first convert the image to HSV, then filter via colors:

```py
hsv_img = cv2.cvtColor(orig_img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)
lower_blue = numpy.array([150, 10, 0])
upper_blue = numpy.array([200, 50, 255])
mask = cv2.inRange(hsv_img, lower_blue, upper_blue)
```

However, I haven't found good values for `lower_blue` and `upper_blue`, and I am afraid there is no single such combination for my use case. In HSV the image looks like this:

[image: HSV image]

Another approach might be to have mulitple such boundaries, lower and upper, and look for all of them, then combine all identified pixels via `cv2.bitwise_or()`. But that again seems quite cumbersome and error prone.

Is there a another / better approach for this case, beside using neural networks, i.e. solely based on OpenCV?

Comment: For an image like this I'd be tempted to swap to HSV and then get the average hue, then grab all pixels on one side of that average.  No guarantees it would.

Comment: Did you analyze the individual channels? I'm sure one of them can help.

Comment: @JeruLuke If you mean the individual HSV channels, then yes, sure. There is, however, not a single boudary for those values which would help. An option is to create multiple such boundaries and "combine" them, as explained, but this approach seems more like a workaround than a reliable solution.

Comment: Wild guess: Maybe you can identify the lens glare on the plastic and use some form of floodfill / watershed to fill the outline. This is likely very prone error due to sensitive thresholds, but maybe it's worth a try.

Comment: As you can see, the hue and saturation differs in that region. Can you display the single hsv channels individually?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can convert the `BGR` image to the [`CMKY`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CMYK_color_model) color space and see if the *blob of interest* shows mostly in one uniform color in one of the channels. This is pretty much by trial and error. In the image you posted, seems that working directly on the *Yellow* (`Y`) channels yields a good result. Let's check out the code:

```
# Image path
path = "D://opencvImages//"
fileName = "KEQyZ.jpg"

# Reading an image in default mode:
inputImage = cv2.imread(path + fileName)

# BGR to CMKY:
(C, M, Y, K) = bgr2cmky(inputImage)

# Show K:
cv2.imshow("Y", Y)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

This is the `Y` channel:

[image]

The bag is mostly black. If we `threshold` the image we should get a good segmentation. Some `bias` should be useful to adjust a little bit better the threshold value. Let's compute `Otsu's threshold` to get an initial threshold estimation, add some bias and threshold again with the new value:

```
# (Otsu) Threshold:
thresh, binaryImage = cv2.threshold(Y, 0, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY + cv2.THRESH_OTSU)

# (Fixed) Threshold + bias:
thresh = 0.4 * thresh
_, binaryImage = cv2.threshold(Y, thresh, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV)
```

This is the binary image so far:

[image]

Looks good. Let's apply some morphology to isolate the biggest blob:

```
# Apply Morphology:
kernel = np.ones((3, 3), np.uint8)
binaryImage = cv2.morphologyEx(binaryImage, cv2.MORPH_ERODE, kernel, iterations=3)
binaryImage = cv2.morphologyEx(binaryImage, cv2.MORPH_DILATE, kernel, iterations=3)
```

This is the result:

[image]

Not bad, let's compute the blob's `bounding rectangle` and draw it on the original image:

```
# (Optinal) Get Bounding Rect:
boundRect = cv2.boundingRect(binaryImage)

# (Optional) Draw the rectangle on the input image:
# Get the dimensions of the bounding rect:
rectX = boundRect[0]
rectY = boundRect[1]
rectWidth = boundRect[2]
rectHeight = boundRect[3]

# (Optional) Set color and draw:
color = (255, 0, 0)
cv2.rectangle(inputImage, (int(rectX), int(rectY)),
              (int(rectX + rectWidth), int(rectY + rectHeight)), color, 2)

# Show the image:
cv2.imshow("Bag", inputImage)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

Which yields the following result:

[image]

OpenCV does not have a `bgr2cmyk` conversion, the function is pretty much the conversion formula directly implemented like this:

```
# Converts BGR to CMYK (as a tuple of 4 arrays)
def bgr2cmky(bgrImage):
    bgrdash = bgrImage.astype(float) / 255.
    # Calculate K as (1 - whatever is biggest out of Rdash, Gdash, Bdash)
    K = 1 - np.max(bgrdash, axis=2)

    # Calculate C
    C = (1 - bgrdash[..., 2] - K) / (1 - K)
    C  = 255 * C
    C  = C .astype(np.uint8)

    # Calculate M
    M = (1 - bgrdash[..., 1] - K) / (1 - K)
    M  = 255 * M
    M  = M.astype(np.uint8)

    # Calculate Y
    Y = (1 - bgrdash[..., 0] - K) / (1 - K)
    Y  = 255 * Y
    Y  = Y.astype(np.uint8)

    return (C, M, Y, K)
```

Comment: Nice answer! RGB to CMYK code is very useful.

Comment: Take a look at the histogram of the `C` image with a reasonable bin size (e.g. `bins='fd'`). It's very much bimodal, with a pretty clear split point at 51 or so.

Comment: @MadPhysicist What do you mean by "reasonable bin size", what does `bins='fd'` mean?

Comment: That is a very nice solution, thanks. A question though: Why do you first perform an Otsu threshold and then a 2nd, "normal" one, and why do you need to bias the Otsu threshold value?

Comment: @Matthias. If you plot a histogram, `plt.hist(C.ravel(), bins='fd')`, you will see an interesting result that corresponds perfectly to what this answer is talking about. As far as Otsu goes, you'll need to look at the data and read up on the estimator to understand what it does.

Comment: @MadPhysicist Ahh now I get it - I was working with `cv2` histograms, but haven't found any option with `fd`, but now it makes sense. Thanks!

Comment: For the records: A discussion on CMYK conversion performnance can be found here; https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73236048/is-there-no-faster-way-to-convert-bgr-opencv-image-to-cmyk - the accepted answer reduces runtime by more than a factor of 10,