# Is there no faster way to convert (BGR) OpenCV image to CMYK?

Tags: python, algorithm, numpy, opencv, image-processing

I have an OpenCV image, as usual in BGR color space, and I need to convert it to CMYK. I searched online but found basically only (slight variations of) the following approach:

```py
def bgr2cmyk(cv2_bgr_image):
    bgrdash = cv2_bgr_image.astype(float) / 255.0

    # Calculate K as (1 - whatever is biggest out of Rdash, Gdash, Bdash)
    K = 1 - numpy.max(bgrdash, axis=2)

    with numpy.errstate(divide="ignore", invalid="ignore"):
        # Calculate C
        C = (1 - bgrdash[..., 2] - K) / (1 - K)
        C = 255 * C
        C = C.astype(numpy.uint8)

        # Calculate M
        M = (1 - bgrdash[..., 1] - K) / (1 - K)
        M = 255 * M
        M = M.astype(numpy.uint8)

        # Calculate Y
        Y = (1 - bgrdash[..., 0] - K) / (1 - K)
        Y = 255 * Y
        Y = Y.astype(numpy.uint8)

    return (C, M, Y, K)
```

This works fine, however, it feels quite slow - for an 800 x 600 px image it takes about 30 ms on my i7 CPU. Typical operations with `cv2` like thresholding and alike take only a few ms for the same image, so since this is all `numpy` I was expecting this CMYK conversion  to be faster.

However, I haven't found anything that makes this significantly fater. There is a conversion to CMYK via `PIL.Image`, but the resulting channels do not look as they do with the algorithm listed above.

Any other ideas?

Comment: "*the resulting channels do not look as they do with the algorithm listed above*" that's because `PIL` follows `RGB` color channel ordering, while `OpenCV` follows `BGR` ordering. Use `cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_RGB2BGR)` and compare the results.

Comment: be sure to use float32, not float64. CPUs and GPUs work faster if you don't use excessive precision. -- you calculate some values multiple times, e.g. `(1-K)`. don't. -- throw numba.jit at the problem. it can accelerate some numpy operations, and it _will_ accelerate operations that you perform using explicit python loops. -- watch that your values don't exceed 0..1 or 0..255 because that'll wrap around in the .astype. use np.clip

Comment: @JeruLuke I don't think that is the issue. When I load the image directly via `PIL` and then convert it to CMYK and then look at all 4 channels, none of them look as the resulting 4 channels I get from the custom function shown above.

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz Thanks, changing to `numpy.float32` reduces runtime from 32 to about 30 ms. Interestingly, when using `numpy.float16` it takes more than one second. Why is that so much slower and not faster?!

Comment: because your CPU doesn't do fp16 in hardware. fp16 is usually found in newer graphics cards but not CPUs. the CPU doesn't have instructions and circuitry to perform this operation, so it has to be emulated with some integer math, possibly wrapping single-precision floating point math.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are several things you should do:

- shake the math
- use integer math where possible
- optimize beyond what numpy can do

###### Shaking the math

Given

```
RGB' = RGB / 255
K = 1 - max(RGB')
C = (1-K - R') / (1-K)
M = (1-K - G') / (1-K)
Y = (1-K - B') / (1-K)
```

You see what you can factor out.

```
RGB' = RGB / 255
J = max(RGB')
K = 1 - J
C = (J - R') / J
M = (J - G') / J
Y = (J - B') / J
```

###### Integer math

Don't normalize to `[0,1]` for these calculations. The `max()` can be done on integers. The differences can too. `K` can be calculated *entirely* with integer math.

```
J = max(RGB)
K = 255 - J
C = 255 * (J - R) / J
M = 255 * (J - G) / J
Y = 255 * (J - B) / J
```

###### Numba

```py
import numba
```

Numba will optimize that code beyond simply using numpy library routines. It will also do the parallelization as indicated. Choosing the `numpy` error model and allowing `fastmath` will cause division by zero to not throw an exception or warning, but also make the math a little faster.

Both variants significantly outperform a plain python/numpy solution. Much of that is due to better use of CPU registers caches, rather than intermediate arrays, as is usual with numpy.

First variant: **~1.9 ms**

```py
@numba.njit(parallel=True, error_model="numpy", fastmath=True)
def bgr2cmyk_v4(bgr_img):
    bgr_img = np.ascontiguousarray(bgr_img)
    (height, width) = bgr_img.shape[:2]
    CMYK = np.empty((height, width, 4), dtype=np.uint8)
    for i in numba.prange(height):
        for j in range(width):
            B,G,R = bgr_img[i,j] 
            J = max(R, G, B)
            K = np.uint8(255 - J)
            C = np.uint8(255 * (J - R) / J)
            M = np.uint8(255 * (J - G) / J)
            Y = np.uint8(255 * (J - B) / J)
            CMYK[i,j] = (C,M,Y,K)
    return CMYK
```

Thanks to Cris Luengo for pointing out further refactoring potential (pulling out `255/J`), leading to a second variant. It takes **~1.6 ms**

```py
@numba.njit(parallel=True, error_model="numpy", fastmath=True)
def bgr2cmyk_v5(bgr_img):
    bgr_img = np.ascontiguousarray(bgr_img)
    (height, width) = bgr_img.shape[:2]
    CMYK = np.empty((height, width, 4), dtype=np.uint8)
    for i in numba.prange(height):
        for j in range(width):
            B,G,R = bgr_img[i,j] 
            J = np.uint8(max(R, G, B))
            Jinv = np.uint16((255*256) // J) # fixed point math
            K = np.uint8(255 - J)
            C = np.uint8(((J - R) * Jinv) >> 8)
            M = np.uint8(((J - G) * Jinv) >> 8)
            Y = np.uint8(((J - B) * Jinv) >> 8)
            CMYK[i,j] = (C,M,Y,K)
    return CMYK
```

This fixed point math causes floor rounding. For round-to-nearest, the expression must be `((J - R) * Jinv + 128) >> 8`. That would cost a bit more time then (~1.8 ms).

###### What else?

I think that numba/LLVM didn't apply SIMD here. Some investigation revealed that the Loop Vectorizer doesn't like any of the instances it was asked to consider.

An **OpenCL** kernel might be even faster. OpenCL can run on CPUs.

[Numba can also use **CUDA**](https://numba.readthedocs.io/en/stable/cuda/index.html).

Comment: This is a great solution, I can confirm a very large speed increase from 30 ms to 1 ms on my machime. Thanks a lot!

Comment: The loop with Numba is faster because you don’t have to deal with large intermediate matrices. Nice writeup!

Comment: You could precompute 255/J, would save a few operations, though you’d have to do that using floating-point arithmetic.

Comment: excellent point on the 255/J. doesn't necessarily need floats, just some fixed point math (mul and bit shifts).

Comment: it feels like numba/LLVM is smart enough to pick whatever division is better, given that the result ends up being uint8 anyway. there seems to be no difference between `/` (float division) and `//` (integer division) in the code here... that I can measure on my fairly busy system anyway.

Answer (score 3):

I would start by profiling which part is the bottleneck.

e.g how fast is it without the `/ (1 - K)`calculation?
-> precalculate `1/(1-K)` might help. Even precalculation of `255/(1-K)` is possible.

```
K = 1 - numpy.max(bgrdash, axis=2)
kRez255=255/(1 - K)

with numpy.errstate(divide="ignore", invalid="ignore"):
    # Calculate C
    C = (1 - bgrdash[..., 2] - K) * kRez255
    C = C.astype(numpy.uint8)

    # Calculate M
    M = (1 - bgrdash[..., 1] - K) * kRez255
    M = M.astype(numpy.uint8)

    # Calculate Y
    Y = (1 - bgrdash[..., 0] - K) * kRez255
    Y = Y.astype(numpy.uint8)

return (C, M, Y, K)
```

But only profiling can show if it is the calculation at all which slows down the conversion.